# The user must enter a string that is greater than 6 characters long

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, subroutine

How can I code this using subroutines in java with a loop so if they don't get it right it keeps repeating till they do. This is all i have so far. The user must enter a string that is greater than 6 characters long.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package containsmethod;

import java.util.*;  
import java.lang.String;  
import java.lang.Character;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ContainsMethod {

    
   public static boolean isValid(String password) {

    if (password.length() < 6) {
    return false;
    } else {
    char c;
    for (int i = 0; i < password.length() -1; i ++) {
    c = password.charAt(i);
    if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(c)) {
    return false;
    } else if (Character.isDigit(c)) { 
        return false;
            }
    }
    }
    return false;
   }

 
   
    
            
    public static void main (String [] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    {
    System.out.print ("Please enter a string that is greater than 6 characters long. ");
    String password = input.next();
    if (isValid(password)) {
    System.out.println ("That is a valid string onto stage 2.");
    } 
    else 
    {
    System.out.println ("That is a invalid string. Try again.");
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your isValid function never returns true, even the case that user enters a password that is greater than 6 characters. So you should update your method like that:

```
public static boolean isValid(String password) {
        if (password.length() < 6) {
            return false;
        } else {
            char c;
            for (int i = 0; i < password.length() - 1; i++) {
                c = password.charAt(i);
                if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(c)) {
                    return false;
                } else if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Then, you can take the user input in a do-while loop. So if the password is invalid it will keep asking. Here is your updated main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        {
            String password;
            do {
                System.out.print("Please enter a string that is greater than 6 characters long. ");
                password = input.next();
                if (isValid(password)) {
                    System.out.println("That is a valid string onto stage 2.");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("That is a invalid string. Try again.");
                }
            }while (!isValid(password));
        }
    }
```

Comment: omg thanks so much you have no idea how much this is appreciated ! THANK YOU!

Comment: I still need help here and there with more questions is there any chance of way I could reach you that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Anjola Adejoro If your are satisfied this answer and believe is the best solution to your problem please accept the answer. If you have other queries please create another question(s) detailing the problem.

Comment: @moken I am satisfied with the answer thanks to everyone.